# Resize plot in Shiny dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

**Problem**

I use the code below to dynamically change the size of a `shinydashboard::box` via javascript. This works fine in principle, but the image from `plotOutput` inside the box does not re-render properly in terms of size. That is, the plot width stays the same irrespective of the size of the surrounding `box`. Funny enough, when I use `Inspect` in Chrome to have a look at the source code, the graph suddenly gets resized.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Question**

How do I need to adapt my code to resize the plot on `input$cols` changes? It is important to mention that in my real code, the content of the box is dynamically rendered via modules. Thus, I have little control over the `renderPlot` function itself. As the image gets resized as soon as I 'inspect' it, I hope that there is a javascript function which I could call, which does the job for me.

---

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(glue)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput("cols", NULL, c(2, 3, 4, 6, 12), 4)),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
      box(solidHeader = TRUE,
          title = "Box",
          width = 4,
          status = "info",
          sliderInput("sld", "n:", 1, 100, 50),
          plotOutput("plt")
      ), id = "box-parent")
  )) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    cols <- req(input$cols)
    runjs(code = glue('var $el = $("#box-parent > :first");',
                      '$el.removeClass(function (index, className) {{',
                      'return (className.match(/(^|\\s)col-sm-\\d+/g) || []).join(" ")',
                      '}});',
                      '$el.addClass("col-sm-{cols}");'))
  })

  output$plt <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(input$sld), rnorm(input$sld)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I found a solution using `$(window).trigger('resize')`. Anything I might overlook with this approach?

Comment: You're probably safe with that. I generally try `width = "100%"` in the `plotOutput()` function first to let the CSS adjust the width. If that doesn't work, triggering a resize may be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, tried it with `width=100%` but did not work, so I will stick with the `trigger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For somebody stumbling on this, here's a solution. The problem arises from the fact that `Shiny` has no idea that something was resized, as everything was done on the javascript level without letting `Shiny` know that we did resize elements. To do so, you have to explicitly call the `window.resize` handle via `$(window).trigger('resize')`.

This explains by the way the behavior, why the plot gets resized properly as soon as you `Inspect` the element, becasue in this case the `resize` event is also triggered and in this routine `Shiny` re-scales plots apparently.

Comment: could you please add a code as an example?